# Can I open IDM using wine in ubuntu if i had IDM already installed in windows(dual booted)? if yes, how?

Tags: dual-boot, wine, idm

I have windows and Ubuntu operating systems i.e. dual booted on my laptop, and I have installed wine latest version. I already have IDM installed in windows.

How can I use it or open it in ubuntu. I know I can install it from wine new setup but I don't wanna install it again(trial version) when I have full version in windows. Is there any way?

Comment: No, there isn't. OSes in dual- or multi-boot are totally independent. And you don't need IDM, there are dozens of native alternatives. Native software is *always* preferable.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia can u tell me the names of some native downloading softwares which are free and works like IDM??

Comment: I think uGet is the closest match.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia from where I can download and install it, and after installing how can i integerate it in mozilla?

Comment: The software is already available in the Ubuntu official repositories and it can be installed like any other software. The Ubuntu Software app should *always* be you first stop when searching for software. Once installed open it and adjust the settings (if I remember correctly it can replace Firefox's download feature or just be started independently by pressing shift while clicking the link; also - I think - it places an additional option in the right-click menu).

Answer (score 0):

No, i dont think so...

Either :

1. Download the IDM instaler and install it under wine. Open terminal :
     wine /path-to-installer/instaler.exe
2. install an alternative :

sudo apt-get install uget

Comment: If i install IDM under wine then is there any change occurs in windows IDM soft?   Because i don't want to change the IDM in Windows.

Comment: No, but still would be easier to install an alternative. I use wine a lot, and almost never easy to install random stuff. So almost every program i want to run/install require me to make some adjusts.